# How do I create an Android application to convert Text to Speech?

Tags: android

![enter image description here][1]I am working an Android application where I am using both a text to speech conversion and speech recognition elements.  However, when I give a repeat instruction or press a repeat button in order to start tts to speak , it throws these warnings:

```
**speak failed: not bound to TTS engine**

**stop failed: not bound to TTS engine**
```

What do I need to do for this to work?

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: If you have to ask, I think you should look here: http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/components/other.html#TextToSpeech  No offense, applies to me too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that you call `speak` only after `onInit` is called.

Comment: Hoan, thanks for replying , as i know when i define an object of tts ,  onInit tts method is called. and i have create object,and even on repeat button, i have create a new object for tts,  and then call speak method, but i still get an error

Comment: onInit is asynchronyous, so after you initialize TextToSpeech you have to set a flag say mIsReadyToSpeak in onInit and when you call speak you have to check for this flag. Or you can disable your speak button and enable it in onInit

Comment: I had tried this, but i get different error of stack overflow

Comment: If i stop tts object by calling tts.stop() or tts .shutdown () and from other place i just call tts.speak(), then what will happen ,does tts speak ?

Comment: If you call stop() then you can call speak again. But if you call shutdown() then you have to create the tts again